# Angular5 reverse routing

Tags: angular, routes

Is there any built-in feature or popular library that allows to avoid hard-codding urls in views? Maybe there is a library to reverse Routes objects and generate type-safe builders for them?

There are 2 reasons I need such feature:

1. Hard-codded urls are hard to support, you cannot change it in single place so it changes everywhere
2. Hard-codded urls are not checked for correctness, although application have Routes array and potentially can check everything at compile/launching

Comment: Hi I have added a implementation for you, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want such a thing it would be really easy to make by yourself. You could export make your routes as constants and import it everywhere you would like to use.

**Step 1**

Create a file called `routes.ts` where you export your routes:

```js
export const HOME = 'home';
export const ABOUT = 'about';
export const CONTACT = 'contact';
```

**Step 2**

Import your `routes.ts` file wherever you want to use the routes and refer to your routes:

```js
import * as routes from './routes';
```

*Example 1 app.routing.ts:*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import * as routes from './routes';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: routes.HOME,
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: routes.ABOUT,
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: routes.CONTACT,
    component: ContactComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*Example 2 home.component.ts and home.component.html:*

Import your `routes.ts` file inside your `home/about/contact.component.ts`.

Then refer inside your `home/about/contact.component.html` towards your variables:

```
<a [routerLink]="routes.HOME">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="routes.ABOUT">About</a>
<a [routerLink]="routes.CONTACT">Contact</a>
```

**Your goals**

This way you achieve your both of your goals:

1. You can change the variable values in one place (the `routes.ts`
   file).
2. You only use the routes which you have defined inside the routes.ts
   file. That way the routes will always work.